# Mvvmcross: handling global app events

Tags: c#, mobile, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

Using MvvmCross, what's the beast way to implement global Application events?

Case 1: app launch - i want to PIN protect my app, so on FinishedLaunching i want some object to check if the PIN has been set and, in case it has not, launch a modal view to ask the user for PIN. The modal view should hide the underneath navigation without popping or modifying any loaded view.

Case 2: logoff - the user, through an mvvm command, removes the PIN from the app and the modal view blocks all other views without unloading them. In this case the model that stores the PIN publishes an event and some  should get that event showing the modal view.

This could be easy to implement on the appdelegate, but i would like to know if there is a better MVVM way of doing this, some kind of ViewModel for the app itself that responds to events exposing the behaviour in the core library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want these type of events to be handled at an app/singleton level, then you can easily do this using:

1. some kind of specialist service initialised in each UI project which uses the `Messenger` plugin to listen to messages
2. some kind of native object on each platform to send messages when key native events happen
3. additional `ICommand` implementations in `ViewModel`s to send User-initiated events

MvvmCross does actually contain an initial implementation to help with 2 - each platform provides a singleton `IMvxLifetime` object

- https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Platform/IMvxLifetime.cs
- https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Platform/MvxLifetimeEventArgs.cs

This is implemented on each platform using:

- Android - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxAndroidLifeTimeMonitor.cs
- Touch - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Platform/MvxApplicationDelegate.cs
- WinPhone https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone/Platform/MvxPhoneLifetimeMonitor.cs

However, in practice this `IMvxLifetime` implementation has never been particularly heavily used - certainly when I've used it a couple of times I've found myself having to workaround issues on a few platforms.